# De-serializing json format string

Tags: c#, string, websocket, deserialization

Currently I have a websocket application that receives response from the server.

I am using

```
object obj=new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CustomerNTF>(e.data);
```

to deserialize the json string.

The string that I am supposed to de-serialize is:

```
{
  "face_list":[
      {
         "face_detect":{
              "age":65535,
              "beauty":65535,
              "expression":65535,
              "gender":65535,
              "glass":false,
              "smile":65536
           },
           "face_recg":{
           "confidence":82,
           "name":"user",
           "person_id":"person1"
        }
       }
     ],
    "face_num":1,
    "msg_id":"FACE_DETECT"
}
```

What I have tried:

```
public class CustomerNTF
{
    public face_list face_list { get; set; }
    public int face_num{get;set;}
    public string msg_id{get;set;}
}
public class face_list
{
    public class face_detect
    {
        public int age { get; set; }
        public int beauty { get; set; }
        public int expression { get; set; }
        public int gender { get; set; }
        public bool glass { get; set; }
        public int smile { get; set; }
    }
    public class face_recg
    {
        public int confidence { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string person_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving is that the deserialization of arrays does not support the type `face_list`.

Comment: Don't post your interpretation of the error, read and research the actual error. `public face_list face_list` should be a collection, not a single item, and there's more wrong with your classes. You can generate proper classes according to a JSON structure through "Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes" in Visual Studio, or on http://json2csharp.com.

Comment: @CodeCaster Did not know there was a json string converter thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your class structure is wrong. The json string contains a list of `face_list` not a single object. Furthermore your current `face_list` class does not contain any properties just two nested class definitions which will not hold any values.

Correct structure:

```
public class FaceDetect
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public int beauty { get; set; }
    public int expression { get; set; }
    public int gender { get; set; }
    public bool glass { get; set; }
    public int smile { get; set; }
}

public class FaceRecg
{
    public int confidence { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string person_id { get; set; }
}

public class FaceList
{
    public FaceDetect face_detect { get; set; }
    public FaceRecg face_recg { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerNTF
{
    public List<FaceList> face_list { get; set; }
    public int face_num { get; set; }
    public string msg_id { get; set; }
}
```

In the future if you are not sure how your class structure has to look like to match a given json string you can use a tool like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com). Which generates the correct structure for you.

Comment: Ah, did not know about the tool json2csharp, just heard about the term de-serializing yesterday so I thought I would give it a try, thanks for the suggestion!